# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck at starting

Tags: 18.04, permissions, startup, root, users

I tried to make my user as root by editing /etc/passwd file and replaced 1000 with 0 for my user.

I restarted my system then a new screen appeared to create user. I created new user and reverted changes in /etc/passwd file. I replaced 0 with 1000 to my user.

I restared again but now system stuck at "[OK] Started wait until snapd is fully seeded.

Comment: No, no, no. Do not try to create a user named root in Ubuntu ! Ubuntu is designed not to have a user named root !

Comment: Oh no! Can't do that. Are you able to boot into Recovery Mode?

Comment: @heynnema Finally issue solved. I tried to access root user via Recovery Mode. I edited the /etc/passwd file. What I saw is a duplicate id of two users. The previous one and the one I created from the root. Finally, I changed the id of the newly created user and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Finally issue solved. I tried to access root user via Recovery Mode. I edited the /etc/passwd file. What I saw is a duplicate id of two users. The previous one and the one I created from the root. Finally, I changed the id of the newly created user and everything works fine now.